# Connect to h2 database

Tags: c#, .net, h2

From H2 database file layout, the db filename is xxx.h2.db

I have tried H2Sharp and Java IKVM, both produce a db filename follow this rule xxx.data.db

This make .net project not able to connect to xxx.h2.db, any workaround ?

Please advise and thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get a file named "test.data.db", then you are using a *very* old version of H2 (version 1.1.x., from 2009 I believe). It looks like H2Sharp did not update the H2 version since then.

There are some instructions how to [build H2Sharp yourself](https://code.google.com/p/h2sharp/wiki/BuildingH2Sharp). However I don't know if that is still working with the latest version.